# Convert Array to formatted string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array element

```
    [{
    "x": 326,
    "y": 176
}, {
    "x": 244,
    "y": 300
}, {
    "x": 189,
    "y": 420
}, {
    "x": 154,
    "y": 546
}, {
    "x": 139,
    "y": 679
}, {
    "x": 152,
    "y": 827
}, {
    "x": 183,
    "y": 954
}, {
    "x": 230,
    "y": 1088
}, {
    "x": 291,
    "y": 1217
}, {
    "x": 365,
    "y": 1333
}, {
    "x": 446,
    "y": 1417
}, {
    "x": 554,
    "y": 1469
}]
```

i want to convert this to string like this

```
"{326,176},{244,300},{189,420},{154,546},{139,679},{152,827},{183,954},  {230,1088},{291,1217},{365,1333},{446,1417},{554,1469}"
```

How can we achieve this in javascript.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: _I have an array element_ that's not an array, that's a **string**, an _invalid_ string.

Comment: do you also need the braces around {326,176}....?

Comment: @Tushar sorry for that now i have updated the question.Thanks

Comment: @user2181397 yes i need exactly in the same way i.e "{326,176},{244,300},{189,420},{154,546},{139,679},{152,827},{183,954},  {230,1088},{291,1217},{365,1333},{446,1417},{554,1469}"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using a combination of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
var ele = '[{"x":326,"y":176},{"x":244,"y":300},{"x":189,"y":420},{"x":154,"y":546},{"x":139,"y":679},{"x":152,"y":827},{"x":183,"y":954},{"x":230,"y":1088},{"x":291,"y":1217},{"x":365,"y":1333},{"x":446,"y":1417},{"x":554,"y":1469}]';

var array = JSON.parse(ele);
var string = array.map(i => '{' + i.x + ',' + i.y + '}').join();

console.log(string);
```

This outputs:

```
{326,176},{244,300},{189,420},{154,546},{139,679},{152,827},{183,954},{230,1088},{291,1217},{365,1333},{446,1417},{554,1469}
```

---

**Update**

Using newer language features like [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), the `map()` operation can now be rewritten as follows:

```js
var ele = '[{"x":326,"y":176},{"x":244,"y":300},{"x":189,"y":420},{"x":154,"y":546},{"x":139,"y":679},{"x":152,"y":827},{"x":183,"y":954},{"x":230,"y":1088},{"x":291,"y":1217},{"x":365,"y":1333},{"x":446,"y":1417},{"x":554,"y":1469}]';

var array = JSON.parse(ele);
var string = array.map(({x, y}) => `{${x},${y}}`).join();

console.log(string);
```

Comment: var array = JSON.parse(codes[0]); 
                                                                                                         codes[0] values is  [Object { x=326,  y=177}, Object { x=244,  y=300}, Object { x=189,  y=421}, Object { x=154,  y=546}, Object { x=139,  y=679}, Object { x=152,  y=827}, Object { x=183,  y=954}, Object { x=230,  y=1087}, Object { x=291,  y=1217}, Object { x=365,  y=1332}, Object { x=447,  y=1416}, Object { x=554,  y=1468}]
Error: 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: You don't need to parse it if it's already an array object. Just leave out the parse step.

Comment: works like a charm.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Be careful with the arrow notation (`=>`) for the inline function. Older browsers will not support it, so you'll have to pass the more explicit `function(i) { return '{' + i.x + ',' + i.y + '}';}` as an argument to `map()`.

Comment: @Robby just a little point, you don't need to pass a ',' to join method as it is by default added between array elements.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Yup, you're right.